# failed to load config from vite.config.js ( RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded )

Tags: node.js, vite

trying to run a project locally . i can not understand why gives me this error
even after i update npm and node but still gives me error

failed to load config from C:\Users\atii\Desktop\project\myapp( $$ Backend ++ Front End )\myapp\client\vite.config.js
[1] error when starting dev server:
[1] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

here is my vite.config.js

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import macrosPlugin from 'vite-plugin-babel-macros';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

  return {
    plugins: [react(), macrosPlugin()],
    root: './',
    build: {
      outDir: 'dist',
    },
    publicDir: 'src',
    server: {
      fs: {
        allow: ['..'],
      },
    },
    define: {
      'process.env': env,
    },
  };
});
```

this is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "samurai",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "npm run build && vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fvilers/disable-react-devtools": "^1.3.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "autosize": "^5.0.1",
    "easymde": "^2.16.1",
    "framer-motion": "^6.3.11",
    "gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
    "import": "0.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dotenv": "^0.1.3",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-github-login-button": "^1.0.1",
    "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-login-github": "^1.0.8",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-simplemde-editor": "^5.0.2",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "remark-breaks": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "twin.macro": "^2.8.2",
    "vite": "^2.9.15",
    "vite-plugin-babel-macros": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "babelMacros": {
    "twin": {
      "config": "./tailwind.config.js",
      "preset": "styled-components"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my .env file

```
BASE_URL=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

i did update node and npm but it did not worked for me .

when i delete .env file it is working . but with .env file not working . the problem is .env file

Comment: if anyone need more information ask in the comment section . i will answer instantly

Comment: I added more information. what is wrong with my .env file that cause this error ?